# IE too slow when adding a lot of HTML to the DOM via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance, internet-explorer

I have a page where we are using a Kendo UI template to generate a bunch of HTML to insert into the DOM.  We are talking 2+ million bytes.  All the other browsers will display this in about 2 to 3 seconds or so.  I'm already avoiding jQuery and setting the innerHTML via the document.getByElementId call.  It appears that the slowest part is regexp.test calls that IE makes.  Is IE vaidating that all the start/end tags match?  If so, is there a way to tell IE to skip this check to speed things up (i.e. "Trust me")?  I've already reduced the HTML needed to as small as possible already, so that is really no longer an option.  Also, the data I'm showing isn't even the largest dataset yet, so I know it'll get a lot bigger.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Update:

This is the current code I'm using:

```
 var resultHtml = kendo.template(templateHtml, { useWithBlock: false })(currentPage.ViewModel);
 resultHtml = resultHtml.replace(new RegExp("\>[\n\t ]+\<", "g"), "><"); // Get rid of whitespace
 document.getElementById("tblData").innerHTML = resultHtml;
```

In IE, this ends up taking about 10 seconds to show with 2.5 million characters being generated.  In Chrome/FireFox/Opera, this takes about 2 to 3 seconds.

Comment: The regexp.test calls that IE makes, or that JQuery makes under IE?

Comment: It appears to be IE that makes this call because it happens after setting the innerHTML directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not appear to be the HTML being added to the DOM now.  It has to do with all the objects I have to 2-way bind with Kendo MVVM.  Sorry about that!

Comment: One thing to also note here is that it ended up being that when you get to a certain element depth, IE also takes a lot longer so if you can only generate the very top levels and generate the other levels when a user drills into them, IE will perform better, too.

Answer (score 1):

Implement something like "double buffering".

Create a node that is not part of the DOM.

```
var offlineNode = $('<div />');
```

Render your contents to the *offline* node.

```
offline.html(kendoTemplate(billionData));
```

Once you finish, move the entire node to the DOM.

```
offlineNode.appendTo($('#a-place-in-dom'));
```

IE has problems guessing when to re-render the page, so it is sensible to DOM manipulation. Every time you make massive DOM changes, IE will be slow.

Comment: This ended up making take even longer, actually.

Comment: Seems like there's nothing I can do for you... Think about enabling pagination. Rendering the data is one thing. Keeping the memory footprint low and the UI responsive is another thing. You will never find a solution to this two things if you never stop rendering massive amount of HTML.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I just put some more finely tuned alerts in and it appears to not be the adding to the DOM part... it is the Kendo bind that is causing issues...